# Make the header items to act as links

Tags: angular

I have this code, and I want when I right-click to this header I don't have the option that The header items to act as links. 
This is my code.

(They do not allow to right-click and open in another window. )
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

try using anchor tag instead of span

```
<button mat-button
    routerLink="/why-us"
    routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="menu-button" translate>nav.why-us</a>
  </button>

  <button mat-button
    routerLink="/browse"
    routerLinkActive="active" class="marginCatalogButton">
    <a class="menu-button"  translate>nav.browse</a>
  </button>
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't now work, I don't know if you understood good what I need when I do right-click it would be possible in the menu that the page can be open in a new window @Ashok

Answer (score 0):

Put routerLink and routerLinkActive inside an anchor. I have this code in my webpage and it works

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/article">ARTICLES</a>
```

Edit-- Providing full example of my webpage.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark">
      <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="['/coding']">DEVELOPING</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="['/fitness']">FITNESS</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="['/creativity']">CREATIVITY</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']" fragment="bgimg-5">ABOUT</a>
  </div>
```

[image: Its in spanish, buy ou can see it works]

Comment: I get something wrong on the syntax @Zamar how should I do this

Comment: Can you provide me an example please, so i can get the right use case @Zamar

Comment: Put the anchor OUTSIDE of BUTTON and see if it works